# Need to know pdf of "x/z+sqrt(y^2-x^2)/z" , or any idea about its upper/lower bounds

Tags: random-variable, density-function, bounds

I need to know the pdf of the following equation or any upper/lower bound would help. Let $X, Y, Z \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. Then what is the distribution of:

$$A=\frac{x+ \sqrt{\mid y^2 - x^2 \mid}}{z}$$

The goal is to know the probability of: $-5<A<5$. Is there any tool or any series expansion to approximate this?

Comment: What does your formula mean when $|x| \gt |y|$??

Comment: there is an abs inside sqrt, thanks for the comment

Comment: I edited your question, please check if I got the equation right.

Comment: If you only want to estimate such chances, simulation may be a good choice.  In about a second of computing time you can locate this probability between $0.834$ and $0.835$ with high confidence (it's close to $0.8344$).

Comment: Thanks @whuber, can you help how you do the simulation for this one? do you use the deterministic formulas for normal pdf with integration or using series? if so what series?

Comment: In `R` it's straightforward: `n <- 1e6;
xyz <- matrix(rnorm(3*n), nrow=3, dimnames=list(c("x","y","z")));
a <- (xyz["x",] + sqrt(abs(xyz["y",]^2 - xyz["x",]^2))) / xyz["z",];
p.hat <- mean(abs(a) < 5);
signif(c(Estimate=p.hat, 'Standard error'=sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/n)), 4)` (The value of $\sigma$ is immaterial, because the distribution of $A$ does not depend on it.)

Comment: Thanks @whuber, can you explain why sigma is not important. Also a bit more clarification i need: what is dimname variable? why is n<1-e6? what is n here? what language did you use?

Comment: Please re-read the first two words of my comment. $\sigma$ is irrelevant because it's a scale factor but $A$ is unitless.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{X}{Z}$ is a cauchy RV (has support $[-\infty, \infty]$)

$Y^2 - Z^2$ follows a scaled variance gamma distribution (difference of two chi squared with equal df, scaled by sqrt sigma. Has support also $[-\infty, \infty]$)

I don't think the absolute and square root functions on the variance gamma will follow any named distribution but its results on the pdf should be straight forward enough to calculate yourself. It will change the support to $[0,\infty]$

The resulting RV over $Z$ is a ratio distribution. You need to do some sort of convolution to test the pdf but as $Z \in [-\infty, \infty]$ it will also have support $[-\infty, \infty]$.

In the end the support should be $[-\infty, \infty]$

Comment: Analyzing this as a sum ignores the dependence between the two terms created by the nontrivial appearance of $x$ in each.

Comment: @whuber I agree, this doesn't robustly determine the PDF, it was more just a quick analysis on the support which doesn't change in the presence of the nontrivial appearance of $x$ in both, and was his second question.

Comment: Thanks @TilefishPoele, but I would like to know the chance of the output of this equation being between -5 and 5 for example. So would like to have some idea about the final pdf or some approximate equation.